# Getting duration for multiple columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time

I have a dataframe, df as below:

| Station | SSD | ASD | EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PM111 | 26-MAY-2021 04:30:00 PM | 26-MAY-2021 05:00:00 PM | 26-MAY-2021 05:10:00 PM |
| PM123 | 26-MAY-2021 07:00:00 PM | 26-MAY-2021 08:00:00 PM | 26-MAY-2021 08:20:00 PM |
| CM111 | 26-MAY-2021 10:00:00 PM | 26-MAY-2021 10:30:00 PM | 26-MAY-2021 10:40:00 PM |

How can I get the Duration,

If Station starting with "PM***" : Duration starting from ASD until EndTime

```
df['Duration']=df.eval("EndTime-ASD").dt.total_seconds()
```

If Station starting with "CM***" : Duration starting from SSD until EndTime

```
df['Duration']=df.eval("EndTime-SSD").dt.total_seconds()
```

How can I get this and store in dataframe, df. Expected Output:

| Station | SSD | ASD | EndTime | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PM111 | 26-MAY-2021 04:30:00 PM | 26-MAY-2021 05:00:00 PM | 26-MAY-2021 05:10:00 PM | 600 |
| PM123 | 26-MAY-2021 07:00:00 PM | 26-MAY-2021 08:00:00 PM | 26-MAY-2021 08:20:00 PM | 1200 |
| CM111 | 26-MAY-2021 10:00:00 PM | 26-MAY-2021 10:30:00 PM | 26-MAY-2021 10:40:00 PM | 2400 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `df.eval()` takes exceptionally long time to process.  It's better to convert your date columns to datetime format and substract the datetime format values directly:

```
import numpy as np

df['Duration'] = np.where(df['Station'].str.startswith("CM"),
                         (pd.to_datetime(df['EndTime']) - pd.to_datetime(df['SSD'])).dt.total_seconds(),
                         (pd.to_datetime(df['EndTime']) - pd.to_datetime(df['ASD'])).dt.total_seconds()).astype(int)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

  Station                      SSD                      ASD                  EndTime  Duration
0   PM111  26-MAY-2021 04:30:00 PM  26-MAY-2021 05:00:00 PM  26-MAY-2021 05:10:00 PM       600
1   PM123  26-MAY-2021 07:00:00 PM  26-MAY-2021 08:00:00 PM  26-MAY-2021 08:20:00 PM      1200
2   CM111  26-MAY-2021 10:00:00 PM  26-MAY-2021 10:30:00 PM  26-MAY-2021 10:40:00 PM      2400
```

If it is possible `Station` starting other than "PM***" or "CM***" (just in case of data input error), and you want to flag this out e.g. by setting the `Duration` to some special value e.g. `NaN`, you can also use [`np.select()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), as follows:

```
import numpy as np

condlist = [df['Station'].str.startswith("PM"), 
            df['Station'].str.startswith("CM")]

choicelist = [(pd.to_datetime(df['EndTime']) - pd.to_datetime(df['ASD'])).dt.total_seconds(),
              (pd.to_datetime(df['EndTime']) - pd.to_datetime(df['SSD'])).dt.total_seconds()]

df['Duration'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default=np.nan)
```

**Result:**

(Added a new test case at the last row):

```
print(df)

  Station                      SSD                      ASD                  EndTime  Duration
0   PM111  26-MAY-2021 04:30:00 PM  26-MAY-2021 05:00:00 PM  26-MAY-2021 05:10:00 PM     600.0
1   PM123  26-MAY-2021 07:00:00 PM  26-MAY-2021 08:00:00 PM  26-MAY-2021 08:20:00 PM    1200.0
2   CM111  26-MAY-2021 10:00:00 PM  26-MAY-2021 10:30:00 PM  26-MAY-2021 10:40:00 PM    2400.0
3   XX999  26-MAY-2021 10:00:00 PM  26-MAY-2021 10:30:00 PM  26-MAY-2021 10:40:00 PM       NaN
```